# Fedora 20 systemctl nginx permission denied

Tags: linux, nginx, systemd, fedora20

I've installed fedora 20 in VMware Workstation on Windows 7. Everything goes okay until I install `nginx` via `yum install nginx`. After editing nginx.conf (only changed location / root)

> ```
>     location / {
>         root   /mnt/hgfs/www;
>         index  index.html index.htm;
>     }
> ```

I try to start nginx via `systemctl start nginx`. Nginx is active but can't access to root folder. Log says `13: Permission denied`. I'm sure nginx has the permission to access the folder.

At first, I thought it might because of HGFS. I changed root to `/usr/share/nginx/html`, than problem solved. But I won't use this folder as my root.

So I mount a new disk via `mount /dev/sdb1 /www` (formatted as ext4), set 777 and change nginx.conf. Then the problem shows again.

The reason why I specify `systemctl` is that I try to run nginx just by `sudo nginx`. Anything goes perfect and no error shows up.

Does `systemctl` have issues with a different filesystem? But sdb1 is the same format as origin filesystem.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: I try to change nginx root to `/`. Then something strange happens. When running nginx by `sudo nginx`, all folders are shown, but running nginx by `systemctl nginx start`, three folders disappear which are `/root` `/lost+found` `/www`. What is the difference between these two ways?

Comment: what are the permissions on `/mnt/hgfs/www`? See if you can see that directory as `nginx`: `# sudo -u nginx ls -l /mnt/hgfs/www/`

Comment: @pferate yes, I can see it. I think there might be something like chroot to disable displaying these folders.

Comment: "I've installed fedora 20 in VMware Workstation on Windows 7." - nothing in that sentence is code. Please do not use backticks in there.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Those backticks weren't used by myself, they were edited by JordanD.

Comment: @ThiefMaster What's wrong with you to close my question which asked a long time ago?

Comment: It's not a programming question. That's why I closed it as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of SELinux, which uses a different way to manage privileges.